# How to apply the effects of weight painting instantly?

Tags: weight-painting

I am having problems when I weight paint. I can paint and the color shows as expected, but the corresponding mesh movement only happens after click on an item in the tool shelf,  eg. belly How can I apply the movement instantly?

cheers jan

Comment: I have no idea what button on the tool shelf you are talking about "belly" Are you using some rig with buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Select your mesh and in the properites panel, modifiers tab, enable thoose little two buttons on the armature modifiers: in this way you will be able to see the effect of all weight paint strokes in real time.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your comment. But it did not solve the problem. I still have to click on a tool shelf item. I use Avastar 2.0 it might a part of the problem?